# Using the concat() function with a variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am having trouble using the concat() function in MySQL to create a string that displays a date. The issue appears to be with passing a variable or function to the concat function.

```
SELECT client.client_name AS Client Name
   , month(curdate()) AS exp1
   , concat('2012/' , '5' , '/' , '6') AS exp2 
   , concat('2012' , '/' , month(curdate())) AS exp3
   , concat('2012/' , client.start_day_of_month) AS exp4
FROM client
GROUP BY client.client_name
```

The results show as follows:

```
Client Name |  exp1 | exp2       | exp3    |    exp4
Client A    |   10  |   2012/5/6 |    BLOB |     BLOB
```

I am not able to get the concat() to work with exp3 and exp4:

```
   concat('2012' , '/' , month(curdate())) AS exp3
   concat('2012/' , client.start_day_of_month) AS exp4
```

I think this is due to passing the function or variable to concat(), but I can't figure out how to get it to work properly. I've tried all types of syntax/quotes but can't seem to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it by `casting`

```
 CAST(month(curdate()) AS CHAR(25))
```

Comment: where would I do that within the statement?

Comment: inside concat, `concat('2012' , '/' , CAST(month(curdate()) AS VARCHAR(25))) AS exp3`

Comment: sorry it's not `VARCHAR` but rather it's `CHAR`